# requirements for a social networking android app

Tags: mysql, hadoop, amazon-web-services, social-networking

i am planning to make an android app for social networking with at most user base of 10000.
with almost the full-fledged feature of a social networking site
So estimating the maximum concurrent users to be 1000,please help in the following points

1. whether MYSql will work fine or should i use MYSql with hadoop?
2. whether i should go with Amazon EC2 or a shared hosting account
       of GoDaddy.com is sufficient?

because I am unable to estimate the complexity  and scalabiity of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are asking if you should use Hadoop, i suspect you have no idea what its for. In your case, likely not.
2. Shared hosting probably wont be enough. But this depends on factors that are impossible to estimate without a lot more information.

Comment: i havent used hadoop but its used executing large amount of parallel queries.
we are going to implement almost all the features of a social networking sites like messaging,chat,sharing pics,lots of posts,likes,comments etc except videos.Is the detail sufficient?

Comment: Its used primary for data warehousing and data mining applications. You wont need it unless you need to analyze large amounts of data. (10's to 100's of GB)